# Ubuntu installation on PC hard drive

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu but at start up the hard drive doesn’t recognize it. Then, when I run Ubuntu from the Ubuntu 14.01 DVD the Files are on the hard drive as if the installation was successful. 
I have tried this on different computers with the same results. The PC I am using has a hard drive with Windows. It works perfectly. I took out the hard drive with Windows. I put in a new hard drive to install Ubuntu. It installs but when the PC boots it doesn’t recognize Ubuntu although it is on the hard drive.
If this is a simple fix please help. Thank you in advance.